# Why can not read sprite from unity3D NGUI Atlas?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

I make a Atlas in unity3D from one picture.

Then cut many sprites as follows.

[image]

But in prefab,there is still only one sprite.

[image]

Is there any way to solve it?

Or I only can create Atlas from many pictures instead of only one?

Comment: It seems you are mixing Unity and NGUI? Are you certainly NGUI now uses Unity's own sprite system? It used to rely on its NGUI sprite system the last time I used it, so the two may not mix.

Comment: You are right.When I create Atlas from not only one picture,actually NGUI create sprites automatically. Just I cut the sprites using the same name with pictures that I think I create the sprites by myself not by system.